# Which data structures to implement tree with two leaf type?

Tags: c++, stl, genetic-programming

Hi which data structures will be the best and the easier to implement tree with two leaf type for example leaf, which contains int and leaf, which contains pointer to function. I need this to genetic programming.

I do this on my own, but i am afraid this is bad idea.

node.h

```
#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int(* func) (int, int);

using namespace std;

class node
{
private:
    node * left, * right, *parent;
    int i;
    int type; //0 - term, 1 - func

public:
    node(node* parent,node* left,node* right, int i, int type);
    ~node();

    void changeLeft(node* left);
    void changeRight(node* right);
    void changeParent(node* parent);
    node* getLeft();
    node* getRight();
    node* getParent();
    int getI();

    virtual func getFunction(){return 0;}
    virtual int getTerminal(){return 1;}

    void show();
};

#endif // NODE_H
```

tree.h

```
#ifndef TREE_H
#define TREE_H

#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

#include "node.h"
#include "nodefunc.h"
#include "nodeterm.h"
#include "functionset.h"
#include "terminalset.h"

using namespace std;

enum typeInit
{
    GROW_INIT,
    FULL_INIT
};

enum typeNode
{
    TERMINAL_NODE,
    FUNCTION_NODE
};

class tree
{
public:
    vector <node*> nodes;
    int depth;
    int counterNodes;

private:
    node* root;
public:
    tree(int depth);
    ~tree();

public:
    void initialize(typeInit type);
    void show();
    node* getRoot();
    int run();

private:
    void initializeGrow(functionSet functions, terminalSet terminals, node* subroot, int depth);
    int initializeFull(functionSet functions, terminalSet terminals, node* subroot, int depth);
    int showSubtree(node* subtree, int depth);
    int runSubtree(node* subtree, int depth);
};

#endif // TREE_H
```

Comment: I think that this is OK. if you want tree you can use map..
This is a tree structure

Comment: Do you really mean leaf, or it is node you meant. Leaf is the node in a tree that does not connect to any child node. Also do you mean in the same tree, some nodes (or leaf if I stick to your original word) might hold an integer value, and some might hold a function pointer. Or do you mean a tree might  be used to store integer values and another tree might be used to store function pointers? Also what is the application of your tree? I don't see any search or find methods in your declaration.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I mean node, not leaf.
@Alon so what if.
node* A;
node* B;
A->changeLeft(B);
delete B;
I think this might be some problem.

Comment: You may have a look to the `Visitor` Design Pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can further develop your idea using a tagged union:

```
enum typeNode {TERMINAL_NODE, FUNCTION_NODE};

class node
{
    union
    {
      int i;
      func f;
    };

    typeNode type;

    // ...
};
```

Only one of the types can be in use at any one time and the `type` field explicitly indicates which one is in use.

Along this way you could also use [boost::variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/variant.html) in place of the anonymous union.

A different approach is using a `symbol` base class:

```
class symbol
{
public:
  virtual int eval(int [] = nullptr) = 0;

  // ...
};

class terminal : public symbol
{
public:
  virtual int eval(int []) override;
  {
    return i;
  }

  // ...

private:
  int i;
};

class function1 : public symbol
{
public:
  virtual int eval(int params[]) override;
  {
    return f(params[0], params[1]);
  }

  // ...

private:
  func f;
}
```

and the `node` class is something like:

```
class node
{
  node *left, *right, *parent;
  symbol *s;

  // ...
};
```

Since the `function` class is stateless, you need to pass some parameters to the `eval` function. This is an annoyance but helps to keep simple other parts of the genetic program (e.g. building the tree, tree recombination...).

Comment: I create two subclass: nodeFunc and nodeTerm and it works, but i am thinking if better is to use stl data structures for example map.
Here example: http://archive.gamedev.net/archive/reference/programming/features/coretree1/page2.html

What do you think about it?

Comment: @user3191398 With a custom tree traversal is very efficient. I wouldn't change with a `std::map` based representation. Perhaps you could consider encodings like [MEP](http://www.mep.cs.ubbcluj.ro/) to store a tree in a vector.

Answer (score 0):

Use three-address code: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-address_code.
This is much more easier to work with.

Have a look to the implementation of a linear genetic programming variant called Multi-Expression programming which uses it: http://www.mepx.org